# Batch size impact on accuracy in LSTM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am working on a Pytorch LSTM model that is able to detect patterns in sequence of N variables that leads to a good outcome vs bad outcome.

I tested it with a simple test-case which has 12 training examples.

I see that using batch size of 1 (i.e compute loss function, call .backward() and .step() after every sample) results in 1s and 0s being separated much more compared to updating loss function once with all samples).  Difference is shown below.

1. Can someone give me the intuition behind this behavior?
2. Is there a rule of thumb of batch size to use based on training data size?  Smaller Batch size makes things slow but I assume there is also higher chance things may not converge?

**Final predictions with batch size 1**

```
Train set targets: [[0.0]], predictions:[0.24779687821865082]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.9567258954048157]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.8191764950752258]
Train set targets: [[0.0]], predictions:[0.20435290038585663]
Train set targets: [[0.0]], predictions:[0.1295892596244812]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.9186112284660339]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.6797895431518555]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.9642216563224792]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.9764360785484314]
Train set targets: [[0.0]], predictions:[0.670409619808197]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.7026165723800659]
Train set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.8404821157455444]

Test set targets: [[0.0]], predictions:[0.08575308322906494]
Test set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.7602054476737976]
Test set targets: [[1.0]], predictions:[0.7767713069915771]
```

**Final predictions with batch size that includes all samples**

```
Train set 
targets: [[0.0], [1.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0], [1.0]], 
predictions:[0.6307732462882996, 0.6873687505722046, 0.6007956862449646, 0.7481836080551147, 0.7676156759262085, 0.6568607091903687, 0.7259970307350159, 0.597843587398529, 0.6819412708282471, 0.6660482287406921, 0.5785030126571655, 0.7716434597969055]


Test set 
Targets: [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0]], 
Predictions:[0.36408719420433044, 0.7265898585319519, 0.7854364514350891]
```

**Code**

**Model**

```
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim):
        super(LSTMFrzModel, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        
        # LSTM
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, batch_first=True)
        
        # Readout layer
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    
    def forward(self, inputs):
        mlp_out, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(inputs)
        output = self.fc(hidden)
        output = self.sigmoid(output)
        return output
```

**Dataset code**

```
class LSTMDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.y)
  
  def __getitem__(self,idx):
    inputs = [torch.from_numpy(self.x[idx][ts]).unsqueeze(0) for ts in range(len(self.x[idx]))]
    inputs = torch.cat(inputs)
    target = torch.Tensor([self.y[idx]])
    return inputs, target
```

**Training code**

```
# This function is used to train a single model
def train_lstm(
    X_training,
    y_training,
    X_testing,
    y_testing,
    hidden_dim=10,
    lr=1e-4,
    f1_thresh = 0.5,
    use_gpu=False,
    batch_size=100,
    num_epochs=4000,
    assym_wt=0, #Equal weights for 0 and 1
):
    start_time = time.time()
    clf = LSTMModel(len(X_training[0][0]), hidden_dim)
    # Move to GPU if available
    use_gpu = use_gpu and torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_gpu else "cpu")

    # Define the loss function and optimizer
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(clf.parameters(), lr=lr)
    clf = clf.to(device)
    loss_function = nn.BCELoss()
    loss_function = loss_function.to(device)

    dataset = LSTMDataset(X_training, y_training)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    # Run the training loop
    # per_epoch_precision = []
    # per_epoch_recall = []
    train_preds = []
    train_targets = []
    for epoch in range(0, num_epochs):
        # Set current loss value
        current_loss = 0.0
        
        # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
        clf.train()  # set to train mode
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
            # Get inputs
            inputs, targets = data                

            # Zero the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Perform forward pass
            outputs = clf(inputs)
            # Store predictions/targets in last epoch to compute accuracy stats 
            if epoch == num_epochs - 1:
                train_targets += targets
                train_preds += outputs.view(-1).tolist()
                print(f'Train set targets: {targets.tolist()}, predictions:{outputs.view(-1).tolist()}')

            # Compute loss
            targets = torch.FloatTensor(targets).unsqueeze(0)
            # Apply assymetric weights to handle unbalanced datasets
            if assym_wt > 0:
                loss_function = nn.BCELoss(weight=assym_wt * targets + 1)
                loss_function = loss_function.to(device)
            loss = loss_function(outputs, targets)
            
            # Perform backward pass
            loss.backward()

            # Perform optimization
            optimizer.step()

            # Print statistics
            current_loss += loss.item()

        if (epoch % 250) == 249:
            print("Loss after epoch %5d: %.3f" % (epoch + 1, current_loss / 500))
            current_loss = 0.0

    # Process is complete.
    print("Training process has finished.")
    train_preds = torch.FloatTensor(train_preds)
    train_targets = torch.FloatTensor(train_targets)

    clf.eval()  # set to eval mode
    dataset = LSTMDataset(X_testing, y_testing)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_preds = []
    test_targets = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for i, data in enumerate(testloader):
            # Get inputs
            inputs, targets = data
            # Perform forward pass
            preds = clf(inputs)
            print(f'Test set targets: {targets.tolist()}, predictions:{preds.view(-1).tolist()}')
            # Store predictions and targets so that we can compute stats
            test_preds += preds.view(-1).tolist()
            test_targets += targets
            
        
        test_preds = torch.FloatTensor(test_preds)
        test_targets = torch.FloatTensor(test_targets)
        pr_fig = go.Figure()
        pr_fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Recall")
        pr_fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Precision")
        plot_pr_withtorch(test_targets, test_preds, pr_fig, "Test PR ")
        plot_pr_withtorch(train_targets, train_preds, pr_fig, "Train PR ")
        pr_fig.show()

        train_F1 = get_scores(train_targets, train_preds > f1_thresh, "Train set scores")
        test_F1 = get_scores(test_targets, test_preds > f1_thresh, "Test set scores")
        print(f"Train time is {time.time() - start_time}")

    return train_F1, test_F1
```

**Test case**

```
# test case
train = np.array([[10, 20, 5, 10, 1], [10, 5, 8, 3, 0], [10, 5, 5, 10, 1]])
for ind in range(0, 3):
    for spread in [5, 10, 50]:
        newrow = spread + train[ind]
        newrow[-1] -= spread
        # print(newrow)
        train = np.vstack([train, newrow])

test = np.array([[0, 8, 3, 7, 1], [19, 8, 12, 3, 0], [1000, 450, 75, 135, 1]])
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train, columns = ['f1_1','f1_2','f2_1','f2_2', 'op'])
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test, columns = ['f1_1','f1_2','f2_1','f2_2', 'op'])
tc_Xtrain = train_df[train_df.columns[~train_df.columns.isin(['op'])]]
tc_ytrain = train_df['op'].astype(np.float32)
tc_Xtest = test_df[test_df.columns[~test_df.columns.isin(['op'])]]
tc_ytest = test_df['op'].astype(np.float32)

#normalize values
scaler = StandardScaler()
tc_Xtrain = scaler.fit_transform(tc_Xtrain)
# print(tc_Xtrain)
# print(f'Type after standard scaler = {type(tc_Xtrain)}')
tc_Xtest = scaler.transform(tc_Xtest)
X_train = np.apply_along_axis(create_ts_features, 1, tc_Xtrain, num_features=2).astype(np.float32)
X_test = np.apply_along_axis(create_ts_features, 1, tc_Xtest, num_features=2).astype(np.float32)
# print(X_train)
# print(tc_ytrain)

train_lstm(X_train, tc_ytrain, X_test, tc_ytest, num_epochs=4000, f1_thresh=0.6, batch_size=100)
```

**Metric computation**

```
def plot_pr_withtorch(target, pred, fig, title):
    pr_curve = PrecisionRecallCurve(pos_label=1)
    precision, recall, thresholds = pr_curve(pred, target)
    print_key_prs(precision, recall, thresholds, title)
    N = len(recall)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=recall[0 : N - 1], y=precision[0 : N - 1], name=title))


def get_scores(y, y_preds, print_label):
    print(f"{print_label} summary:")
    confusion = confusion_matrix(y, y_preds)
    print(f"Confusion matrix: {confusion}")
    print("Accuracy: {:.2f}".format(accuracy_score(y, y_preds)))
    print("Precision: {:.2f}".format(precision_score(y, y_preds)))
    print("Recall: {:.2f}".format(recall_score(y, y_preds)))
    F1_score = f1_score(y, y_preds)
    print("F1: {:.2f}".format(f1_score(y, y_preds)))
    return F1_score
```

Comment: The point of things like stochastic gradient descent is that you use a minibatch (ie. 16 samples at once), not batch the entire data. This essentially limits your model to taking 1 step per epoch, which is clearly suboptimal. Minibatching is a compromise on taker fewer steps than 1 step/sample, but should be quicker and more robust since you are averaging errors between samples.

Comment: Not a *programming* question (despite the code), hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info